# @PropertySource java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring

I am testing Spring's `@Conditional` in which I load the bean depending on the value present in the `.properties` file. So I created a `.properties` file in `src/main/resources/application-config.properties` and I have the configuration class as:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application-config.properties"}, ignoreResourceNotFound = false)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.app.test"})
public class ApplicationContextConfig {...}
```

I have 2 `Condition` implementations as below:

```
public class ConditionalBeanOne implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        String name= conditionContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("condition.name");
        return name.equalsIgnoreCase("condition_one");
    }
}


public class ConditionalBeanTwo implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        String name= conditionContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("condition.name");
        return name.equalsIgnoreCase("condition_two");
    }
}
```

I have respective POJO classes as:

```
@Component
@Conditional(value = ConditionalBeanOne.class)
public class BeanOne implements ServiceBean {}

@Component
@Conditional(value = ConditionalBeanTwo.class)
public class BeanTwo implements ServiceBean {}
```

When I run the application, I get following exception:
`Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application-config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

I am running this through `main` method as following:

```
public class ConditionalMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationContextConfig.class);
        .....
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using ignoreResourceNotFound=false flag? Isn't that the default behavior? Try using  @PropertySource("classpath:application-config.properties")

Comment: Ok, I had it set to true before to test it, then made it false. But would behave as default.

Comment: Also try and see if you had made a spelling error somewhere or share your project structure over here.

Comment: Can someone care to reason for downvote?

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: No, I am not using Spring-Boot.

Comment: I'd set `ignoreResourceNotFound=true` because otherwise you're asking for the exception and shouldn't be surprised.

Comment: Thanks @AbhijitSarkar! I tried to set it before but, as you can see, `Conition` implementations depend on those values from `properties`. So I would get NPE.

Comment: If the property doesn't exist, you'd get NPE on `equalsIgnoreCase`, and you need to code accordingly. Do you want me to also show how to avoid NPE in your code?

Comment: Well, if you tell me the reason to set `ignoreResourceNotFound = true`, then I would be trying to solve the other problem with NPE. In my case I do not want to ignore it. I am trying to find why Spring cannot find the `.properties` file in my resource directory.

Comment: @RossiRobinsion, understood, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't reproduce your problem so I created a complete working example based on your use case, which is also available on my [GitHub](https://github.com/asarkar/spring/tree/master/spring-conditional). I noticed that your conditions are really the same, only the values are different, so you don't really need to duplicate the code there. Other than that, it's pretty much what you did.

I'd say that you're reinventing the wheel here. Spring Boot already has a [ConditionalOnProperty](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) which does this.

**Application.java**:

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext =
                     new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class)) {

            ApplicationConfig.GreeterService greeterService =
                    applicationContext.getBean(ApplicationConfig.GreeterService.class);

            String actual = greeterService.greeting();

            System.out.printf("Greeting: %s.\n", actual);
        }
    }
}
```

**ApplicationConfig.java**:

```
@Configuration
// The / doesn't matter, but I prefer being explicit
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
@ComponentScan
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @FunctionalInterface
    public static interface GreeterService {
        String greeting();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty("hello")
    public GreeterService helloService() {
        return () -> "hello";
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty("hi")
    public GreeterService hiService() {
        return () -> "hi";
    }
}
```

**ConditionalOnProperty.java**:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Conditional(OnPropertyCondition.class)
public @interface ConditionalOnProperty {
    String value() default "";
}
```

**OnPropertyCondition.java**:

```
public class OnPropertyCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        Map<String, Object> attributes = annotatedTypeMetadata
                .getAnnotationAttributes(ConditionalOnProperty.class.getName());
        String value = (String) attributes.get("value");

        String name = conditionContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("greeting");

        return !isEmpty(name) && name.equalsIgnoreCase(value);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**:

```
greeting=hello
```

Run normally:

**Output**:

> Greeting: hello.

Run with `-Dgreeting=hi`:

**Output**:

> Greeting: hi.

Comment: Thanks @Abhijit! This answer definitely helps. However, since `Spring` 4 I can use `@Profile` annotations which has similar implementation as yours. I am aware of it. However, my purpose is to find why `Spring` is not finding the properties file in my `classpath`. If I go this way, it would defeat the purpose of my query.