# how can I limit the context of a @Primary Bean?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inject

I have a bean defined in a appContext named MyBean in MyProject1.

I have in other app that injects all the bean definitions of MyProject1 (including MyBean).

Now I need to override that bean but there is no easy way , so in MyProject2 I make

```
<bean primary="true" class=MyBean />
```

It works great, my question is....

What will happen with all others that were using MyBean? Will now use the new bean with the primary=true or how can I specify which should use this new bean and which should keep using the old one?

Comment: You using Spring Boot? If yes, I can give you more options.

Comment: No, I am not using spring boot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) `primary` bean is used only if there are some candidates to be injected. All created beans are in the context.

If you need only your primary bean to be injected, you can use:

```
@Autowired
private MyBean myBean;
```

So all your old beans will be replaced with primary one.

If you need to handle all `MyBean` beans (for example you do `Chain Of Responsibilities`) you can inject:

```
@Autowired
private List<MyBean> myBeans;
```

and injected object would contain all your bean instances (primary and nonprimary). As Usual primary bean can be accessed from list by `0` index: `myBeans.get(0)`. All alternative markers (for example filter by `vendorType`...) to detect bean that you needs you should specify and handle in you code filtering collection, but in usual way if project architecture doesn't have issues you have no needs make **alternative markers** filtering bean objects in collection.

Do not forget about `singleton` if you need only one bean in your context.

If you have specified different bean unique names you can inject with [@Qualifier](https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/04/a-quality-qualifier) (sometimes using `@Resource` from java API `javax.annotation.Resource`) specifying correspond name as parameter to detect bean by name.

---

Spring provides ability to inject properties using [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html). May be they'll provide new functionality to inject beans using [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) also (it could help you in your issue in best way).

Answer (score 0):

Use [profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) or [@Conditional](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html). `@Qualifier` is meant for resolving conflict for autowire, not for deactivating all but one. When using `@Qualifier`, all the candidate beans are still active.

Using profiles, when you want to use the bean from project2, simply start the app with a profile=project2; the link above describes multiple ways to do that.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44991546/839733) for a complete example of using `@Conditional`.